# ¿Como hacer que aparezcan unos datos específicos en una tabla?

Tags: xml, xslt

Buenas pues tal y como pone en el titulo me gustaría que una tabla xml a traves del xslt aparezcan los datos de por ejemplo las canciones de solo un artista o solo los datos de un sello discografico, pero no se como usar el *xsl if* para que funcione, o si hay que usar ese o no otro, adjunto el codigo de mi xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>musica</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="grey">
                <th>Titulo del album</th>
                <th>Artista</th>
                <th>nombre cancion</th>
                <th>duracion</th>
                <th>Sello discografico</th>
                <th>Año de publicacion</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="musica/cd">

               <xsl:if test= "artista>Avantasia">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="titulo_del_album"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="artista"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="nombre_cancion"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="duracion"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sello_discografico"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="año_de_publicacion"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es dificil responder sin ver tu documento XML, sin embargo, lo más fácil es utilizar XPath en una condición/un predicado añadido en el atributo `select`, por ejemplo

```
<xsl:for-each select="musica/cd[artista = 'Juanes']">
```

solo va a procesar los elementos `cd` cuyo `artista` es `Juanes`.